# Partially show text in MUI Accordion or Card

Tags: material-ui

I want to partially show text in either an MUI Accordion or Collapasible card.  These are to serve as surfaces for reviews.  I want to show some of the review before the rest is cut off, forcing a user to expand the Accordion or Card.  Is this possible with MUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

By using the `collapsedSize` property of the `Collapse` component, you can get the behavior I think you're looking for.  [CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/collapse-text-card-fvg2s6?file=/demo.tsx)

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import Card from '@mui/material/Card'
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'

export default function CollapseTextCard() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }} onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}>
      <Collapse collapsedSize={100} in={expanded}>
        <Typography>
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil et
          aperiam ut accusantium voluptatum. Sequi tenetur fugiat commodi
          reiciendis, repudiandae rem iste eos quod fugit ipsam eius laborum
          impedit ut! Veritatis iure ad voluptate necessitatibus perferendis
          illo nemo. Sunt culpa, voluptatum repellat consectetur nostrum illum
          obcaecati eaque, quisquam magni doloribus, impedit laudantium cumque
          quidem eius reprehenderit nam numquam! Est, illum. Consequatur harum
          quos velit consectetur animi, rerum fugiat ipsa nostrum quo suscipit
          esse delectus id est, quam impedit necessitatibus magnam quidem hic
          expedita dicta natus sunt. Sequi necessitatibus inventore blanditiis.
          Officiis asperiores praesentium cupiditate minus. Magni similique
          veritatis hic aliquam ipsum, quibusdam nemo accusantium perspiciatis
          ea, exercitationem repellat aperiam? Perferendis odit nulla debitis
          molestiae similique maxime culpa suscipit architecto distinctio.
          Pariatur quia voluptatum ducimus nostrum, cum a similique corporis
          sunt repellat reprehenderit architecto nisi aspernatur iusto
          voluptatibus nobis, sint animi inventore explicabo distinctio iure
          voluptate doloribus. Pariatur quis consequatur nobis!
        </Typography>
      </Collapse>
    </Card>
  )
}
```